# what parent i should apply for `<td>` in the ternary operator inside?

Tags: reactjs

I have a scnerio like have to apply parent for `<td>` element inside the ternary operator

```
<tr> 
  <td> id </td> 
  <td> name </td> 
  { row.author == 'anonymous' ? ( <td>{row.author}</td> <td>{row.firstName+' '+row.lastName}</td> ) :
<td  colspan="2">anonymous</td> }
```

Comment: You really should try to do a better job explaining your question. Give a detailed explanation, along with the exact problem your experiencing. Also, try to give a clean presentation of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Fragment to wrap multiple tds.

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';

<tr>
  <td>id</td>
  <td>name</td>
  {
  row.author == 'anonymous' ?
    <td colspan="2">anonymous</td>
    :
    <Fragment>
      <td>{row.author}</td>
      <td>{row.firstName+' '+row.lastName}</td>
    </Fragment>
  }
</tr>
```